# Webview does not show Google map Full control button

Tags: android, android-webview

I implemented one Web Application in android in that i want to call one URL and in that Page Google map is there

My issue is that in google map  `+`, `-` Buttons works perfectly but Fullscreen button shows white blank screen.

It's showing in chrome app

Please, give me a solution?

Comment: Can you provide the URL or some screenshot of the webview?

Comment: Please add the requested info

Comment: Please provide the url and code fragment

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes, post solution..

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this to your webview config .?

yourWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
yourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)